# Python Convert datetime to int for training model

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert [timedelta64[ns]] dtype to int as I want to start training the model but i keep getting the following error:
 TypeError:cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [float64]

I need to convert it to a number dtype before training it, correct?

edit:
I have a dataset and the Y predictor is datatype [timedelta64[ns]] where it predicts how many days a given records day shift was:

X columns (all columns have been converted to numbers through one hot encoder as some were categorical)
Role Type  Phase Bid Value

Y column
Dateshift
20 days
15 days
10 days

So do I need to convert the Y column into int before training the model? If so, how?

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a proper example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a `timedelta` to `float64` by converting to `int` first like this:

```
df['new'] = df.timedelta_column.astype('int').astype('float64')
```

If the end goal is to get the number of days:

```
df['new'] = df.timedelta_column.dt.days
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comments, if you want to use the `float64` value and then bring it back to `timedelta` for interpretation:

```
df['new_float'] = df.timedelta_column.astype('int').astype('float64')
df['new_timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['new_float'])
```

Comment: I can tell it did convert to digits but is there a way I can get the exact digit as in 20 from the 20 days in the column? Or how will i convert value back to understand it?

Comment: If you want the number of days you can use `dt.days`.

Comment: @Zee updated the answer. Feel free to accept if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide `timedelta`, for example:

```
df['timedelta_col'] = df['timedelta_col'] / pd.to_timedelta('1D')
```